# How to catch an exception thrown during a PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I am using MVC\MVVM and WPF. I have a form that is bound to a model and a controller that is catching the PropertyChanged events and evaluating business rules and validations.
Well, I want to pop-up a message when a validation is false telling the user what is wrong and how to fix it. But I'm not sure the "correct" way from the controller. I'd like to throw an exception that can be caught by the view but I can't figure out how.
I've tried Dispatcher.Invoke() but that just got me an unhandled exception at the application level.

How do I trap exceptions that are generated from the PropertyChanged event handler in the Controller?

EDIT: Specifically I have a combobox that has a list of discounts in it. I can't allow an inappropriate selection, but I have to notify the user why the selection is inappropriate. This is not as obvious as a textbox that has integers in it. I need to tell the user the date the customer filled out a survey. They can't use that discount twice. I don't want to exclude the survey discount from the list since that would just look like an error to the user. I need to show them the discount and tell them the customer has used that discount and cannot use it again.

EDIT 2: I have looked over the ValidationRule class and since I have to use a database lookup I don't see how I'm going to keep everything in the Model and still have the business rules in the Controller. I've looked at IDataErrorInfo but that requires me to wrap my Model in my Controller and bind to the Controller instead, but only for one field. I think the best course of action in this case is to have the Controller call a method on the View and pop-up a message.

Answer (score 2):

You are walking down the wrong path.

A good way to handle validation in MVVM is by implementing [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) and setting [`ValidatesOnDataErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx) to `true` on your bindings. You will also almost certainly want to enable `ValidatesOnExceptions` for completeness, and [`NotifyOnValidationError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyonvalidationerror.aspx) so that the binding engine triggers the [`Validation.Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error.aspx) attached event on the control that you have bound the property to.

For more details, see the Validation section on the [MSDN documentation for data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_validation) in WPF.

Some tips:

- .NET 4.5 introduces [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx) and the corresponding [`ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx) binding property that provide beefed-up validation functionality in comparison to `IDataErrorInfo`; you might want to look into that.
- You do not need to actually do anything meaningful inside `IDataErrorInfo.Error` because it is used by the Windows Forms infrastructure and is ignored in WPF. You can even have the getter throw `NotImplementedException`.
- There is good reading material illustrating this approach, complete with examples and code, [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/using-a-viewmodel-to-provide-meaningful-validation-error-messages/) and [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/input-validation-ui-exceptions-model-validation-errors/).

**Update: clarification and example code**

This validation model does not involve implementing a `ValidationRule` yourself at all; your models (i.e. the binding sources) simply need to implement one of the two interfaces. How to implement the interface is entirely up to you; in a past project I implemented basic async validation with

```
public interface IDelegatedValidation : IDataErrorInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when validation is to be performed.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler<DelegatedValidationEventArgs> ValidationRequested;
}

public class DelegatedValidationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DelegatedValidationEventArgs(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public bool Handled { get; set; }

    public string ValidationError { get; set; }
}
```

The model implements `IDelegatedValidation` by exposing an event and with

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
{
    get { return this.GetValidationError(columnName); }
}

private string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
{
    var args = new DelegatedValidationEventArgs(propertyName);
    this.OnValidationRequested(args);
    return args.ValidationError;
}

protected virtual void OnValidationRequested(DelegatedValidationEventArgs args)
{
    var handler = this.ValidationRequested;
    if (handler == null) {
        return;
    }

    foreach (EventHandler<DelegatedValidationEventArgs> target in handler.GetInvocationList()) {
        target.Invoke(this, args);
        if (args.Handled) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So the workflow goes like this:

1. When the model is about to be wrapped by a viewmodel, some appropriate entity that can perform the validation subscribes to its `ValidationRequested` event.
2. The view binds to the model; at some point validation is triggered.
3. The model calls `GetValidationError`.
4. Event handlers get invoked one by one; the first handler that produces a validation error sets `args.ValidationError` and `args.Handled` to `true` so that the chain is stopped.
5. The validation error is returned to the view.

There is an added twist in that if the viewmodel needs to know whether its model is valid or not (e.g. to enable/disable a "save" command) it needs to also tap into this process.

There's really nothing that you *cannot* do with `IDataErrorInfo` / `INotifyDataErrorInfo` because how you implement them is entirely up to you. Definitely have a look at the [Silverlight version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the latter's documentation for more examples; there is also a lot of helpful material [like this](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/18/wpf-4-5-asynchronous-data-validation/) on the internet.

Comment: This isn't passive validation. This is something that requires being looked up in the database and is dependent on the customer's past. I don't see how a ValidationRule is going to cut it. See above for more explanation.

Comment: @TomPadilla: Please have a look at the update. I 'm not sure why you specifically mention `ValidationRule`, that's the one thing you don't need to touch at all.

Comment: I think my problem is the first step in your workflow:
"1) When the model is about to be wrapped by a viewmodel..." This doesn't happen in my architecture. So far I have a Model with data and lookups and a Controller with rules. The Controller can ask the Model to do a lookup but it doesn't "wrap" the Model.

I realize that I mention MVVM in the question, that is because I have yet to have anyone explain the difference between MVC and MVVM any better than "It depends on what you want to call it" so I just use them both. If this is the difference then let me know.